# Is running a lamp dev server secure

Tags: wordpress, development-environment

Curious if there are any security concerns with running a dev server, with a standard lamp setup. More specifically, if I was downloading a new client’s existing Wordpress site with no idea what it’s security standards are like (malacious plugins etc), could I be exposing myself? If this was an issue, would running some sort of vagrant/docker setup be more secure?

Comment: "...could I be exposing myself"? if the client has a security issue in his/her website and you setup the site in your environment then yes.

Answer (score 0):

VM or Vagrant/Docker would be more secure, indeed.

That WP install which

1. may contain small malicious JS code which may copy itself to another path of your localhost and then use your PC as a zombie computer.
2. can harm data of your filesystem (where PHP has an access to)
3. can steal your data

etc.

So, it is obvious that you can't trust it.